# Talend - Dynamic Column Name (Enterprise version)

Tags: dynamic, etl, data-warehouse, talend

Can anyone help me solve this case?

I have much file to process, two of them is like on below screenshot with **my expected output**.

[image: the screenshot of my file input and my expected output]

I use this transformation on Talend: tFileList---tInputExcel---tUnpivotRow---tMap---tPostgresqlOutput

The output is different to my expected output. This is the screenshot of the output

[image: the screenshot of output of transformation]

Can anyone help me to reach **my expected output** which is like on my first picture above?

Answer (score 1):

This will be pretty hard. You'd have to handle that as a text file. And whenever you found "store" value in the first column you'd update your type with the value.

Here's how I'd start:
Basically tJavaFlex begin piece would contain:

```
String col1Type
String colNType
```

main part:

```
if input_row.col0.equalsIgnoreCase("store") {
col1Type = input_row.col1;
col2Type = input_row.col2;
colNType = input_row.colN;
continue; /*(so this record will be Ignored for the rest of the components!)*/
}
output_row.col1Type = col1Type;
output_row.col1Value = Integer.valueOf(input_row.col1); 
/*coz we have text and need numbers :( */
```

I think using propagate results will save you from writing down all the other fields.
And from here it would be very simple as you have key-type-value-type-value-type-value results.